# Android ListView selection when rotated in 3d

Tags: android, listview, 3d, selection

I have the requirement to draw a ListView in 3D rotated some number of degrees rotated around the X axis.  That was easy enough, derive my own ListView, then in the draw() method construct a rotation matrix with android.graphics.Camera and call canvas.setMatrix() with the resulting matrix before calling super.draw(canvas).

However, I also have the requirement that selection still work correctly even when the list is rotated.  Sounds simple.  It's really not that difficult a problem, but I have yet to find a solution that works.  (FWIW, selection also needs to work on Gingerbread).

Looking through the AbsListView code, it looks as though pointToPosition() is called in a couple of places to determine which child is hit.  It's a public method (yay!), so I can override it and maybe get it to select the right position.  Wrong.  That function isn't called when I'm selecting a list item.  Must be one of the other paths...

The other paths in AbsListView's onTouchEvent use mMotionPosition which is found by calling findMotionRow()....which is private in ListView :(.  Can't override that without creating my own ListView derived from AbsListView and cloning all of ListView's code.  Not a small feat.

Another thought was to override ListView's onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event), take the rotation matrix constructed in draw (mRotationMatrix), call event.transform(mRotationMatrix) and according to the docs will transform all the points within 'event' according to the matrix.  (note: this is a Level 11 API, I need to support API Level 10, but I'll take whatever I can get at this point).  Well, using event.transform() doesn't seem to improve things.  It occurred to me that the rotation matrix that I retrieve after calling Camera.rotateX() probably doesn't include the perspective matrix.

Went looking for APIs to retrieve the perspective matrix android must have to use somewhere for drawing views in a perspective manner, but didn't find any.  Even went digging through Skia to see if I could find a perspective matrix hard-coded somewhere.  I saw references for checking whether a matrix was a perspective one or not (checking kPerspective_Mask), but have yet to find a hard-coded perspective matrix.

Any other ideas on how to attempt to get ListView selection to work correctly even when it is rotated?

thanks.